# Emacs on OS X - False "Beginning of buffer"

Tags: macos, cocoa, emacs

I am trying out Emacs for OSX, installed with brew using 
`brew install emacs --HEAD --use-git-head --with-cocoa --with-gnutls --with-rsvg --with-imagemagick`

Its all working good, just one thing I cant figure out, when I try to scroll to the top of a buffer, I get `Beginning of buffer` even though the top line is ..say 33. This is the same if I use the `C-v` keys instead of mousescroll.

Comment: Does this mean that the top line has the wrong number, or does this mean that there are 32 lines above that cannot be accessed?  Does this happen with **Emacs -Q** -- i.e., no user configurations whatsoever?

Comment: I mean 32 lines above that cannot be accessed. Running with -Q flag fixes the problem. Guess I have to go trough my .emacs config file... Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to a misconfiguration of my `(linum-mode)` in my .emacs file. Essentially  @lawlist comment about the `-Q` flag for running Emacs without any settings, led me in the right direction.